# SQL Server 2012 Find bucket wise products and dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below:

```
date        prodname
2018-01-01  Product1
2018-01-05  Product1
2018-01-09  Product1
2018-01-17  Product1
2018-01-24  Product1
2018-01-26  Product1
2018-02-20  Product1
2018-01-02  Product2
2018-01-07  Product2
2018-01-09  Product2
2018-01-17  Product2
2018-01-28  Product2
```

**Code:**

```
CREATE TABLE myTemp(
Date Date,
ProductName varchar(10))

INSERT INTO myTemp values
('2018-01-01', 'Product1')
,('2018-01-05','Product1')
,('2018-01-09','Product1')
,('2018-01-17','Product1')
,('2018-01-24','Product1')
,('2018-01-26','Product1')
,('2018-02-20','Product1')
,('2018-01-02','Product2')
,('2018-01-07','Product2')
,('2018-01-09','Product2')
,('2018-01-17','Product2')
,('2018-01-28','Product2')
```

The table can have any number of date's entries for each product.
I want to display the product name, minimum date and min date + 24 days. And I want to do this for each 25 days' bucket.

For example,
In case of product1, 2018-01-01 is the min date and 2018-01-25 is the PLUS 25 date.
**BUT**, product1 also has records for date greater than 2018-01-25. So I should see one more record for product1 in the output like below:

```
2018-01-26  2018-02-19  product1
```

2018-01-26 being the Min Date after 2018-01-25. 2109-02-19 being the PLUS 25 date. and product1 is the product name.

That way, my final output should be:

```
2018-01-01  2018-01-25  Product1
2018-01-26  2018-02-19  Product1
2018-01-02  2018-01-26  Product2
2018-01-28  2018-02-21  Product2
```

I tried doing it with min() and DateAdd() but it gives me one row for each product.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #MyTemp
select MIN(Date) CurrDate, DateAdd(d, 24, MIN(Date)) CurrPlus25Date, ProductName
into #MyTemp
from myTemp
group by ProductName

select * from #MyTemp
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way using recursive cte. If you have a number / tally table, you can simply take the `product` cte and cross join with the tally table

```
; with 
product as
(
    select  ProductName,
            minDate = min(Date), 
            maxDate = max(Date)
    from    myTemp
    group by ProductName
),
productdates as
(
    select  ProductName, minDate, maxDate, 
        frDate = minDate, toDate = dateadd(day, 24, minDate)
    from    product

    union all

    select  ProductName, minDate, maxDate,
            frDate  = dateadd(day, 1, toDate),
            toDate  = dateadd(day, 25, toDate)
    from    productdates
    where   frDate  < maxDate
)
select  ProductName, frDate, toDate
from    productdates
order by ProductName, frDate
```

Answer (score 0):

This following query will provide your desired output-

```
SELECT C.min_datre,C.Plus_24_date,C.ProductName
FROM
(
    --Select data for the initial Date Range
     SELECT MIN(Date) AS min_datre,DATEADD(DD,24,MIN(Date)) AS Plus_24_date,
     ProductName
     FROM     myTemp
     GROUP BY ProductName

    UNION ALL 

    --Select Data for Out of first defined range
    SELECT MIN(B.Date),
    DATEADD(DD,24,MIN(B.Date)),
    ProductName
    FROM
    (
        --Select records per product with date greater 
        --than overall MIN(Date)+24
        SELECT 
        mt.date Date,
        mt.ProductName,
        A.min_date 
        FROM myTemp mt
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT MIN(Date) min_date,
            DATEADD(DD,24,MIN(Date)) with_24_day,
            ProductName
            FROM     myTemp
            GROUP BY ProductName
        ) A 
        ON mt.ProductName = A.ProductName
        AND mt.Date > A.with_24_day
    ) B
    GROUP BY B.ProductName
) C 
ORDER BY 3,1
```